# ef code first: get entity table name without dataannotations

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first

Is there a way to get table info defined with DbModelBuilder?

something like:

```
entity.GetType().GetTableName()
```

Max

EDIT:

id like to implement following

```
public static class Helper
{
  public string GetTableName(Type type) {
    // ??
  }
}
```

now i'd like to get table name by type

```
var type = someEntity.getType();
var sql = "delete from " + Helper.GetTableName(type) + " where id in (...)"
```

Comment: Could you add some more detail its difficult to figure out what you want.

Comment: Hope this helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313008/how-can-i-extract-the-database-table-and-column-name-for-a-property-on-an-ef4-en/6909752#6909752

Comment: this does not for code first :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only solution i can imagine is reflection. Here it is

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // model mappings

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // table mapping
    var config = modelBuilder.Configurations
        .GetPrivateFieldValue("_modelConfiguration")
        .GetPrivateFieldValue("ActiveEntityConfigurations");

    var mapping = new Hashtable();
    foreach (var c in (IEnumerable)config)
    {
        var type = (Type)c.GetPrivateFieldValue("ClrType");
        var tableName = (string)c.GetPrivateFieldValue("EntitySetName");
        mapping[type] = tableName;
    }
    // store mapping whereever needed
}
```

Main idea is to get configuration object after base.OnModelCreating has called.