# Select column from non-generic DbSet?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ienumerable, dbcontext

I want to implement a function that accepts a `DbSet` (non-generic), a `string`, and `object`, and returns `DbSet`. something like the following pseudu:

```
public static DbSet Any(DbSet set, string propertyName, objectParameter)
{
  var tableName = set.TableName;
  var columnName = set.GetColumnNameForProperty(propertyName); 
  var query = string.Format("SELECT TOP(1) {0} FROM {1} WHERE {0} = {2}",
                columnName, 
                tableName,
                objectParameter);
}
```

I think that SQL query is enough since I'll be able to execute it directly on the Database (`context.Database.ExecuteSql`).

What I want to do is get the table name from the given `DbSet`, then the column name in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible from non generic `DbSet` but this problem can be easily solved by using:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Any(DbSet<T> set, string property, objectParameter)
  where T : class
{ ... }
```

Returning `DbSet` doesn't make sense because once you query data it is not `DbSet` anymore.

The bigger problem is getting table name from generic `DbSet` / `ObjectSet` because this information is not available from those classes. It is almost impossible to get it at all because [it requires accessing non public members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927583/is-there-any-way-to-view-entity-framework-code-firsts-column-mappings-at-runtim/7929287#7929287) of items from `MetadataWorkspace`.