# Getting mapped column names of properties in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

in my project I use Entity Framework 6.
I have these entities:

```
   public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PersonRight> PersonRights { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
 public class PersonRight
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

When I insert a person object with filled in PersonRights it looks like this in the database:

table for Person entity:

```
dbo.People with columns Id, Name
```

table for PersonRights entity

```
dbo.PersonRights with columns Id, Name, Person_Id
```

when I load a person from a database it hasnt filled PersonRights property because of the virtual keyword which is enabeling the lazy loading feature - and its okay.

Then I get the PersonRights for the person object and it also works fine.

The thing is, since there is no navigation property in PersonRight entity, the entity framework must know by which columns in the database are those two properties bounded.
In database ther is a foreign key connecting PersonRights and People tables:

```
FK_dbo.PersonRights_dbo.People_Person_Id
```

The question is : Is there any way how to get the column name by which are those two properties connected?
Any way how to get the string "Person_Id" in code?

There is a way how to find out to which table is an entity bounded in database :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350135/Entity-Framework-Get-mapped-table-name-from-an-ent

thanks a lot for your answers :)

EDIT:

Well I found out that the column name propety is here:

```
  var items = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSSpace);
```

but I still cant reach it, the problem is weird, when I get first item from this collection it shows me that its type is `System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageEntityContainerMapping`
but when I go through it by foreach suddenly the type is `System.Data.Entity.Metadata.Edm.GlobalItem` ...

How can I access the `System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageEntityContainerMapping` item where is also the collection I need to get the column named - `AssociationSetMappings` ??

Comment: ok, I solved the table name problem ( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350135/Entity-Framework-Get-mapped-table-name-from-an-ent) but the foreign key column name problem is still unsolved..

Comment: Consider to post this solution as answer and accept it. It can be helpful for other people

Comment: Why doesn't PersonRight have property Person_Id?  Is this code-first and you only add relationships in the database?

Comment: Yes, it is code first, and Im trying to avoid using navigation properties as much as possible so I did not include the Person_Id property in the PersonRight POCO class. But the mapping was made by entity framework itself and lies in the MetadataWorkspace. I just need to find a way how to reach these informations

Comment: I don't know how replicate your situation; I can delete the navigation property from the model, but not Person_Id without causing errors (generated model from database).  Which begs the question, why not just keep Person_Id in PersonRight but leave out the nav prop?

Comment: the Person_Id column in the database is not deleted, the navigation property Person_Id had never existed. Entity framework itself created the column and knows about this mapping. I just want to get the Person_Id column name from the code. I hope this is more understandable :)

Comment: Created the tables with PersonRight having foreign key Person_Id.  Generated model from that.  Deleted the nav prop in PersonRight.  All's well.  Next step; delete Person_Id simple property (non-nullable int).  Now T4 transformation cannot run, "There is no property with name 'Person_Id' defined in type referred by Role 'PersonRight'"

Comment: I dont think we understand each other:) Ill try to explain it as simply as I can: 1) I have two entities - Person and PersonRight and their whole code is in my post above. 2) Person have as a property collection of PersonRights. 3) PersonRight has no property saying to which Person it belongs, no Preson_Id. 4) In the database there IS a column named Person_Id in table dbo.PersonRights. 5) So entity framework must know that there is a cerrtain relationship between those two. 6) I want to get to the name of the Person_Id column in code, it is contained in ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace ...

Comment: ... the wuestion is : How to get the string "Person_Id" from the ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace object in code? I hope that now it is understandable, Im sorry my knowledge of english is not as good as I would needed sometimes:)

Comment: I understand you perfectly.  What I'm trying to explain is that I've no idea how you arrived there.  When I *attempt* to create a model containing those classes above based on a store that has the constraint you describe, the model won't build.  What I also don't understand is why you can't just add Person_Id to PersonRight.  It exists in the database; it's a legitimate property, why not add it?

Comment: What I consider as great advance in usage of entity framework is to cut off the need to care about the database level, so if I do not need to add Person_Id property to my model (and it really seems that entity framework can handle the relationship by itself since it create the column Person_Id in database) I would rather dont include  it. Im simply finding a way to get information already containt in the Context I use..

Comment: @JohnSmith: try using the generic version of your method. Instead of returning `GlobalItem` objects, it will return objects of the generic type `T`. Something along the lines of `var items = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<PersonRight>(DataSpace.CSSpace);`. If that doesn't work, take a look at [this](http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/entity-framework-get-mapped-table-name-from-an-entity/) blogpost. It looks very promising. All you should have to do is extract the column instead of the table.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I added a hacky answer to your question about how to get the actual column names on one of the linked questions [Find the database field name of a property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510081/find-the-database-field-name-of-a-property/25560450#25560450)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get to the actual string "Person_Id" from the storage model, but you cannot identify that property/column as the foreign key.  For that you would need Person_Id to exist in the conceptual model.  I still don't quite understand why you wouldn't want it in the model, but here's how you would get it from the storage metadata:

```
using ( var context = new YourEntities() )
{
  var objectContext = ( ( IObjectContextAdapter )context ).ObjectContext;
  var storageMetadata = ( (EntityConnection)objectContext.Connection ).GetMetadataWorkspace().GetItems( DataSpace.SSpace );
  var entityProps = ( from s in storageMetadata where s.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType select s as EntityType );
  var personRightStorageMetadata = ( from m in entityProps where m.Name == "PersonRight" select m ).Single();
  foreach ( var item in personRightStorageMetadata.Properties )
  {
      Console.WriteLine( item.Name );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, is there any way how to get the relationship between these columns and actual entities? I still need to find out which column is the foreign key for Person entity...

Comment: @john-smith If you put this `item.MetadataProperties["PreferredName"].Value` in the loop that is iterating the Properties, You will get the corresponding property Name in the EF Entity. I added this comment late, because I needed to find the mapping between the column and the property in the Poco and this post helped me

Comment: @CedricDumont item.MetadataProperties[].Value retrieves the field name not the property name in the POCO model

Comment: Sir, you are awesome!

Comment: This article helped me:  https://romiller.com/2015/08/05/ef6-1-get-mapping-between-properties-and-columns/

Comment: @Jazzy yeah, that article helped more than any other answer or comment on this page )))

Answer (score 2):

For `EF6` I could only find the mappings in `DataSpace.CSSpace` (`EntityTypeMapping` will map entities to tables, and `ScalarPropertyMapping` will map scalar properties to columns):

```cs
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;

// ...

using ( var db = new YourContext() )
{
  var metadataWorkspace = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)db)
  .ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

  var itemCollection = ((StorageMappingItemCollection)metadataWorkspace
  .GetItemCollection(DataSpace.CSSpace));

  var entityMappings = itemCollection.OfType<EntityContainerMapping>().Single()
  .EntitySetMappings.ToList();

  var entityMapping = (EntityTypeMapping)entityMappings
    .Where(e => e.EntitySet.ElementType.FullName == typeof(TEntity).FullName)
    //or .Where(e => e.EntitySet.ElementType.Name == "YourEntityName")
    .Single().EntityTypeMappings.Single();

  var fragment = entityMapping.Fragments.Single();
  var dbTable = fragment.StoreEntitySet;

  Console.WriteLine($"Entity {entityMapping.EntityType.FullName} is mapped to table [{dbTable.Schema}].[{dbTable.Name}]");

  var scalarPropsMap = entityMapping.Fragments.Single()
  .PropertyMappings.OfType<ScalarPropertyMapping>();

  foreach(var prop in scalarPropsMap)
    Console.WriteLine($"Property {prop.Property.Name} maps to Column {prop.Column.Name}");

}
```

Out of curiosity I use the code above because `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` requires mapping between entity properties and table columns.

Comment: congrats with your 1000! :)

Comment: Thanks for this @drizen. Presumably, in order to use this with `SqlBulkCopy` you had to identify the column names as well as the column types. Do you have the code for that? (Or alternatively the SqlBulkCopy configuration code you used that doesn't require specifying column types?)