# Entity Framework - Check if property is mapped

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, inotifypropertychanged

I'm using Entity Framework and am triggering a property changed event, where I'd like to update a property if the property that changed is mapped.

```
protected void FooPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var notMappedArray = typeof(Foo).GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotMappedAttribute), false); // I thought this might return null if the property did not have the attribute. It does not.
    //if (notMappedArray == null)
    UnitOfWork.Value.GetRepository<Foo>().Update(MyFoo);
}
```

What is the best way to find if a property sent to this event is mapped in entity framework?

Edit: I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161854/getting-mapped-column-names-of-properties-in-entity-framework). However, it seems like the answer is going a little overboard, and doesn't quite do what I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My problem was in my Foo class. I apparently had a floating `[NotMapped]` attribute far above the property I was checking. I ended up using something like this:

```
protected void FooPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var notMapped = typeof(Foo).GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotMappedAttribute), false);
    if (notMapped.Length == 0)
    {
        UnitOfWork.Value.GetRepository<Foo>().Update(MyFoo);
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx , it's so useful