# Find the database field name of a property

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have an EntityFramework model with a property `Prop` that is mapped to a field in the table - `PropField`. I want to find the field's name (`PropField`) at runtime.

I followed the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20245546/871910) and received a list of `EntityType`s. One of them is indeed of `Prop`, but it only contains the property's name, not the field name in the database.

I accessed the `DataSpace.CSpace` metadata, and received a list of database fields. `PropField` is indeed there, but there's no association between `PropField` and `Field`. Using `DataSpace.CSSpace` didn't return anything meaningful.

How can I find the field's name?

Answer (score 0):

Building on that answer I came up with this extremely hacky reflection solution - the fields are clearly there, but I can't find any legitimate way to access them. I'm only using it for unit testing, so no big deal if it breaks.

```
    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    var storageMetadata = ((EntityConnection)objectContext.Connection).GetMetadataWorkspace().GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace);
    var entityProps = (from s in storageMetadata where s.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType select (System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType)s);
    var entityName = "OrderItem";
    var entityStorageMetadata = (from m in entityProps where m.Name == entityName select m).Single();
    var pi = typeof(System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType).GetProperty("ForeignKeyBuilders", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var fkBuilders = (IEnumerable<object>)pi.GetValue(entityStorageMetadata);
    Type builderType = fkBuilders.First().GetType();
    var builderProps = builderType.GetProperties();

    var fullPropsToColumns = fkBuilders.Select(x => new
    {
        PropertyName = builderProps.First(p => p.Name == "Name").GetValue(x).ToString().Split('_')[1],
        FieldName = ((IEnumerable<object>)builderProps.First(p => p.Name == "DependentColumns").GetValue(x)).First().ToString()
    });
```