# how to map back to get the actual sql table column name apart from model in MVC?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am mapping my table column name to generic way in to use them in model.
like:

```
        public UserEntityMapper()
        {
            ToTable("tbl_User");

            HasKey(m => m.UserKey);
            Property(p => p.InsuredKey).HasColumnName("User_KEY");
            Property(p => p.FirstName).HasColumnName("FIRST_NAME");
        }
```

Iif i know FirstName field has been modified on the page using model, then need to know that the column name in the sql table is 'First_Name'

Anyway approach to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### Reading the mappings

I've seen similar questions before and several less than satisfying solutions based on splitting the SQL string generated by a `DbSet`. Attempts to access the mapping metadata are blocked by unaccessible internal types. It kept (and keeps) bugging me that this information is so hidden. Atter all, it's your own mapping.

So I did some fooling around to see if something can be improved here. Since everything can easily be read from an edmx file, that's where I started. And finally got there. It the following code, the edmx file is in an `XDocument` called `doc`. I'll explain the code below.

```
var xn = XName.Get("Mappings", doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().ToString());
var mappingsNode = doc.Descendants(xn).Descendants().First();
var mappingDoc = XDocument.Parse(mappingsNode.ToString());
xn = XName.Get("MappingFragment", mappingDoc.Root
                                            .GetDefaultNamespace().ToString());
var mappings = mappingDoc
            .Descendants(xn)
            .Select(x => new
                {
                    Entity = x.Attribute("StoreEntitySet").Value,
                    Mapping = x.Descendants()
                                .Select(d => new 
                                            { 
                                              Property = d.Attribute("Name")
                                                          .Value,
                                              Column = d.Attribute("ColumnName")
                                                        .Value
                                            })
                });
```

Sample output from a very small edmx:

```
Entity      Property        Column
---------------------------------------------
Category    CategoryID      CategoryID 
            Name            CategoryName 
            Description     Description 

Product     ProductID       ProductID 
            Name            ProductName 
            QuantityPerUnit QuantityPerUnit 
            UnitPrice       UnitPrice 
            StartDate       StartDate
```

#### Explanation:

An edmx file has a fixed structure that I summarize here:

```xml
<Edmx Version='3.0' xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx'>
  <Runtime>
    <ConceptualModels>
    ...
    </ConceptualModels>
    <Mappings>
      <Mapping Space='C-S' xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs'>
        <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer='CodeFirstDatabase' CdmEntityContainer='UserQuery'>
          <EntitySetMapping Name='Categories'>
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName='CodeFirstNamespace.Category'>
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet='Category'>
                <ScalarProperty Name='CategoryID' ColumnName='CategoryID' />
                ...
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <AssociationSetMapping Name='Category_Products' TypeName='CodeFirstNamespace.Category_Products' StoreEntitySet='CategoryProduct'>
          </AssociationSetMapping>
        </EntityContainerMapping>
      </Mapping>
    </Mappings>
    <StorageModels>
    ...
    </StorageModels>
  </Runtime>
  <Designer>
  ...
  </Designer>
</Edmx>
```

The `Mappings` part is what we're after. So I first create a new `XDocument` of this part:

```cs
var xn = XName.Get("Mappings", doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().ToString());
// First descendant of the "Mappings" node, which is the "Mapping" node
var mappingsNode = doc.Descendants(xn).Descendants().First();
var mappingDoc = XDocument.Parse(mappingsNode.ToString());
```

The "Mapping" node has its own namespace, so I parse it into an `XDocument` in order to get this namespace by which I can query its nodes. Thus, I can get to the mapping fragments:

```cs
xn = XName.Get("MappingFragment", mappingDoc.Root
                                            .GetDefaultNamespace().ToString());
var mappings = mappingDoc.Descendants(xn) ...
```

Maybe there is a better way to get to these nodes, but I'm not very fluent in this `XDocument` API.

Then it's a question of pulling out the right attributes and project them to a queryable structure.

#### Thoughts

It works, OK, but it's not elegant at all. It greatly depends on the edmx structure, so it can break any moment. I think there should come a decent, convenient way to read a context's metadata.

By the way, if you work code-first you can generate an edmx by an [`EdmxWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.edmxwriter.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Working on another problem I found a much better way to achieve this. I think this wasn't even possible when I wrote the first answer.

To find a store name starting from a CLR type name, we have to access the store-CLR space of the EDM model. That's where mappings between classes and properties on the one hand, and tables and column on the other hand are found. Knowing this it's just a matter of carefully dissecting the content of a deep tree of objects to get the desired results:

```cs
public IEnumerable<
    (
        string StoreName, 
        string ColumnName, 
        string ClrTypeName, 
        string EntitySetName, 
        string PropertyName
    )> GetTableAndColumns<TEntity>()
{
    var entityContainerMappings = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
        .MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSSpace)
        .OfType<EntityContainerMapping>();

    var entityTypeMappings = entityContainerMappings
        .SelectMany(m => m.EntitySetMappings
            .Where(esm => esm.EntitySet.ElementType.Name == typeof(TEntity).Name))
        .SelectMany(esm => esm.EntityTypeMappings).ToArray();

    var propertyMappings = (from etm in entityTypeMappings
                            from prop in etm.EntityType.Properties
                            join pm in entityTypeMappings.SelectMany(etm => etm.Fragments)
                                .SelectMany(mf => mf.PropertyMappings)
                                .OfType<ScalarPropertyMapping>()
                                on prop.Name equals pm.Property.Name
                            select new { etm, prop, pm }
        );
    return propertyMappings.Select(x => 
        (
            x.etm.Fragments[0].StoreEntitySet.Name, 
            x.pm.Column.Name, 
            x.prop.DeclaringType.Name, 
            x.etm.EntitySetMapping.EntitySet.Name, 
            x.prop.Name
        ));
}
```

This is a method inside a `DbContext` subtype. For the specified type, it returns tuples containing

- Table Name
- Column Name
- CLR type name
- Entity set name
- Property name

For instance:

| Store name | Column | Clr type | Entity set | Property |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product | Id | Product | Products | Id |
| Product | ProductName | Product | Products | Name |
| Product | QuantityPerUnit | Product | Products | QuantityPerUnit |
| Product | UnitPrice | Product | Products | UnitPrice |
| Product | StartDate | Product | Products | StartDate |
| Product | RowVersion | Product | Products | RowVersion |