# EF how to obtain the key property when using EntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have a EF Model that is using EntityTypeConfiguration in order to set the configuration of its properties:

```
public EntityMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.MasterEntity);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.MasterEntity)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(10);

            this.Property(t => t.EntityType)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(10);

            this.Property(t => t.Description)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            this.Property(t => t.GlobalEntity)
                .HasMaxLength(10);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("entity");
            this.Property(t => t.MasterEntity).HasColumnName("masterentity");
            this.Property(t => t.EntityType).HasColumnName("entitytype");
            this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("description");
            this.Property(t => t.GlobalEntity).HasColumnName("globalentity");
            this.Property(t => t.Active).HasColumnName("active");
```

Before I was using DataAnnotations and in order to get the primary Key I use:

```
dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties().Single(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), false).Count() > 0).Name;
```

Any clue on how to do that but when using **EntityTypeConfiguration** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `EntityKey` by an extension method I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15896086/861716).

Once you've got the `EntityKey` you can get to the key property name(s) by

```
var keyNames = enityKey.EntityKeyValues.Select (ekv => ekv.Key)
```

Comment: Gert can I use the same approach to get the mapped table name (fluent api)? Appreciate

Comment: No. EF 6.1 has a [Public Mapping API](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Public%20Mapping%20API) which you may want to look at. Otherwise you can get there the hard way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20807366/861716.