# get the name of a column of an entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I am creating a website with asp.net core 3.1 and the entitie framework 6

I would like to get the name of a column of an entity from my database in the code c#.

```
[Table("CORPSDEMETIER")]
public partial class CorpsDeMetier : BaseClass
{
    
    [Column("CODE_CORPS_DE_METIER")]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string CodeCorpsDeMetier { get; set; }

    [Column("LIBELLE_CORPS_DE_METIER")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LibelleCorpsDeMetier { get; set; }

    public IList<EntrepriseCorpsdemetier> EntrepriseCorpsdemetiers { get; set; }
    public IList<ProjetEntrepriseCorpsDeMetier> ProjetEntreprisesCorpsDeMetier { get; set; }

}
```

I have see how to get it with SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID( 'CORPSDEMETIER' )
```

But I dont want ask the database one more time when I think I can get it in the code.

In this case I would like get "LIBELLE_CORPS_DE_METIER"

```
CorpsDeMetier item = new CorpsDeMetier();
string name = item.LibelleCorpsDeMetier. ......;
```

Sory my english is very bad I hope you understand me well.
Thanks for read me.

Comment: In the duplicate, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36190544/861716. This method is independent of how the columns are mapped, by fluent API or attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Reflection and read `ColumnAttribute` Name.

```
 public static class ObjExtenstions
 {
    public static string GetColumnName(this object obj, string name)
    {
        string result = name;

        var property = obj.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(name));
        if (property != null)
        {
            var columnAttribute = (ColumnAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(true).FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(ColumnAttribute));
            result = columnAttribute?.Name;
        }

        return result;
    }
 }
```

Usage (if ColumnAttribute is not used then property name is returned):

```
var name = item.GetColumnName(nameof(CorpsDeMetier.LibelleCorpsDeMetier));
```