# Get Model schema to programmatically create database using a provider that doesn't support CreateDatabase

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using the SQLite provider for Entity Framework 5 but it doesn't support CreateDatabase and thus cannot auto create the database. (Code First)

Is there a way I can obtain the Model schema at runtime so that I can create the SQL "CREATE TABLE" command myself?

If not at runtime, some other way to obtain the schema so I know how to create the table properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A)** As for obtaining the `model schema at runtime` part

(all are earlier posts of mine)

See this one [How I can read EF DbContext metadata programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718301/how-i-can-read-ef-dbcontext-metadata-programmatically/15720297#15720297)

And [How check by unit test that properties mark as computed in ORM model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866272/how-check-by-unit-test-that-properties-mark-as-computed-in-orm-model/15867365#15867365)

Also this one for a custom initializer [Programmatic data transformation in EF5 Code First migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865767/programmatic-data-transformation-in-ef5-code-first-migration/15869721#15869721)

**Having said that...**

**The problem I see is where and at what point you actually have the data available**.
Actually I'm quite sure you won't be able to do that at any time.
Because to be able to extract that info you need to have a `DbContext` running - so db has to be constructed etc. etc.

In the initializer maybe - but using different ways to get that info - the above is not available.

**B)**
The other way would be to go the way of implementing a provider, generator etc. (e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887145/entity-framework-migrationsqlgenerator-for-sqlite/15887646#15887646)).
That way you should get all that info just at the right time from the EF/CF itself.
However I haven't played with that much.

For more info you can check the [EF source code](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/)

This is more of a 'gathered info' so far - in case it helps you get anywhere with it. Not really a solution. I'll add some more tomorrow.

**EDIT:**

To get the real database metadata, look into the other `DataSpace`, this should get you to the right place...
(note: things tend to get `less exact` from here - as obviously there isn't the right official support)

```
var ssSpaceSet = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.SSpace).First()
    .BaseEntitySets
    .First(meta => meta.ElementType.Name == "YourTableName");
```

If you look up in debugger, `Table` property should have the real table name.
However, `reflection` might be required.

---

[How I can read EF DbContext metadata programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718301/how-i-can-read-ef-dbcontext-metadata-programmatically/15720297#15720297)
[How check by unit test that properties mark as computed in ORM model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866272/how-check-by-unit-test-that-properties-mark-as-computed-in-orm-model/15867365#15867365)
[Programmatic data transformation in EF5 Code First migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865767/programmatic-data-transformation-in-ef5-code-first-migration/15869721#15869721)
[Entity Framework MigrationSqlGenerator for SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887145/entity-framework-migrationsqlgenerator-for-sqlite/15887646#15887646)
http://entityframework.codeplex.com/
[Entity Framework - Get Table name from the Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106842/entity-framework-get-table-name-from-the-entity)
[ef code first: get entity table name without dataannotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008212/ef-code-first-get-entity-table-name-without-dataannotations)
[Get Database Table Name from Entity Framework MetaData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895455/get-database-table-name-from-entity-framework-metadata)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350135/Entity-Framework-Get-mapped-table-name-from-an-ent

Comment: Damn, that's nasty but it does appear to have what I need (your part A).

As it turns out, you CAN access this information without a database running. I can get it all in the DatabaseInitializer. 

I'll accept this answer for the time being unless it turns out it won't work.

Comment: Problem found! Obtaining the metadata through the DbContext doesn't return the Table name if set via attributes or the fluent api.

Comment: it's in the different `space` - I just edited in. The only problem is you'd have to use reflection to get there (Table property is `internal`) - but maybe it is exposed somewhere directly.

Comment: there is another option in that code project article (end) - which doesn't / shouldn't load the cf at all, not exact science again, but interesting hack

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. At this point, interestingly enough, it might just be easiest to modify SQLite and do it properly then submit the patch back for inclusion...