# How get database table name with schema name from entity programmatically

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to get the SQL table name for the entity. 
When I work with the MetadataWorkspace queries I get lots of information from the object or the storage space. But schema name and table name are not present.

I try query all the EntityType objects for CSpace and SSpace and I can see both listed correctly but I can't figure out how to get SSpace from CSpace.

So say I have a type in the object model called User - how do I find the tablename with schema name (tkp.User) in the database?

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `perfect` answer to this, but this should work...

```
var ssSpaceSet = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace
    .GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.SSpace).First()
    .BaseEntitySets
    .First(meta => meta.ElementType.Name == "YourEntityName");
```

If you look up in debugger, `Table` property should have the real table name.

> You'd need to use `reflection` in the last part.
>   Good news is it should transparently work with EF6 too 
>   (as it has a similar base class)

(it's similar for `schema`, should be in there also - this is the `space` for Db/SQL mapped names, facets etc.)

See this post of mine with many details
[Get Model schema to programmatically create database using a provider that doesn't support CreateDatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891112/get-model-schema-to-programmatically-create-database-using-a-provider-that-doesn/15891802#15891802)

---

[Get Model schema to programmatically create database using a provider that doesn't support CreateDatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891112/get-model-schema-to-programmatically-create-database-using-a-provider-that-doesn/15891802#15891802)
[How I can read EF DbContext metadata programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718301/how-i-can-read-ef-dbcontext-metadata-programmatically/15720297#15720297)
[How check by unit test that properties mark as computed in ORM model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866272/how-check-by-unit-test-that-properties-mark-as-computed-in-orm-model/15867365#15867365)
[Programmatic data transformation in EF5 Code First migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865767/programmatic-data-transformation-in-ef5-code-first-migration/15869721#15869721)
[Entity Framework MigrationSqlGenerator for SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887145/entity-framework-migrationsqlgenerator-for-sqlite/15887646#15887646)
http://entityframework.codeplex.com/
[Entity Framework - Get Table name from the Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106842/entity-framework-get-table-name-from-the-entity)
[ef code first: get entity table name without dataannotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008212/ef-code-first-get-entity-table-name-without-dataannotations)
[Get Database Table Name from Entity Framework MetaData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895455/get-database-table-name-from-entity-framework-metadata)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350135/Entity-Framework-Get-mapped-table-name-from-an-ent

Comment: Thank you very much. I found out schema name by Schema property.

Comment: How to get schema name from simple DbContext?

Comment: @evc what issue do you have? this is a rough stroke solution and table, schema all is inside, you can get the ObjectContext from the DbContext directly, PaulP mentioned schema property etc. And in EF 6.* (new ones) you have even better ways http://stackoverflow.com/a/18964974/417747 or [here](http://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/)

Comment: oh, found it pretty easy. `(ObjectContext)MyDbContext`