# how to get the sql table name from table type in linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How I can get sql table name in linq

For example :
In linq my table object name is : `TblUserDetail`.

But this table name in sql is `TblUserDetails`.

Comment: LINQ to what? Linq to Entities, Linq to SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var model = _db.Mapping; //_db is the datacontext instance
foreach (var mt in model.GetTables())
   Console.WriteLine(mt.TableName);
```

This will list all *sql* tables' names.

Quoted from [Get all table names](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jomo_fisher/archive/2007/07/30/linq-to-sql-trick-get-all-table-names.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Ling2sql drops the 's' because the plural is used to identify a collection of TblUserDetails in a related entity.

Probably your TblUSer entity will have a TblUserDetails collection (assumption: you have a 1:n relationship)

Answer (score 0):

I've provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6909752/844006) for a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5313008/844006); however, the answer is for Linq to Entities.